# How to find all objects with ids from one number to another in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What query should I use to find all the objects with an id from one number to another. For example, let's say I wanted to find all objects with a primary key from 10 to 20 (between 9 and 21). How would I do this in Rails?

Would this work? `Object.where(:id => (10)..(20))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html):

```
MyModel.where(:id => (10..20))
```

Comment: yeah, exactly what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
Model.limit(11).offset(9)
```

Comment: This depends on the data and on sorting, this certainly won't work always.